# Add Days to PHP Variable

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have 2 variables in PHP. One is getting today's date and adding 1 month to it. That works fine. The other is supposed to take that date and add 6 days to it. For some reason that part refuses to work. Am I simply formatting it wrong? I always get 01-06-1970 in my database.

Here is the variable that gets today's date and adds 1 month (works fine)

```
$renewdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
```

Here is the variable that adds 6 days to $renewdate (does not work)

```
$latedate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days',$renewdate));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second argument of `strtotime` is Unix timestamp. Currently `$renewdate` is a string. So:

```
$latedate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days', strtotime($renewdate)));
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.2.0 brought [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), why are you still sticking to old functions? OOP approach is better!

```
$dtCreate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-08-02 16:16:02');
$dtCreate->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));
```

This will add `6 days` to your `DateTime` object, see [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for details.

After you added an interval, you may `format` your object however you wish:

```
$dtCreate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will return `2016-08-08 16:16:02`, as you can see, it's 6 days later.

Comment: This looks like a good solution but I'm not understanding what the createFromFormat and P6D functions do. Can you break it down? I would like to understand this method better.

Comment: @SpyderTech I provided the links to the official PHP manual, it's all perfectly explained there.